# Custom TextBox Control And Validation Display

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have created a custom TextBox control which also contains a RequiredFieldValidator. Everything works fine but the problem is in display. The display is something like this:

```
[TextBox Control] [Validation Error Message]
```

I want the display to be something like this: (the validation error message should be at the top of the textbox)

```
[Validation Error Messsage] 
[TextBox Control]
```

My control inherits from the TextBox control. How can I create the display like above. I tried to use the Table control and insert TextBox and Validation control inside the Table but it gave me some sort of stack over flow error.

Here is the code:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer) {
    base.Render(writer);

    if(_req != null)
        _req.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

Comment: The ValidationErrorMessage should be at the top of the TextBox!

Comment: Can you attach the code from your Render method?

Comment: If you appending information to the question you should edit the question to do so.

Comment: A stack overflow error means that you (more likely than not) have a recursive function somewhere.  Step through it to find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close to doing it right! Try this:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if(_req != null)
        _req.RenderControl(writer);
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

That will render the validation control before your TextBox instead of afterwards. If you want to change the appearance further then css is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ugly solution:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
           if (_req != null)
           {
               writer.Write("<div style='float:top;'>");
               _req.RenderControl(writer);
               writer.Write("</div>");
           }

           base.Render(writer);
        }
```

Comment: technically float top isn't really doing anything.  the reason this works is because you're calling base.Render after _req.RenderControl as opposed to before.

Comment: the reason its displaying on top is because the default behavior of div is display:block;

Comment: finally its okay to post your own answer to the question, but you should not post updates, like code samples as answers, you should edit your original question to include that. can you update your question and then delete the first answer?

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to be confusing, the bad code should go in the question and then the solution code will be down here in the answer.  This way this question looks nice for people who look later.  Also you will want to make this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Currently I am not able to accept my own answer. It says wait for 48 hours!

Comment: oh I didn't realize,  Can you provide the bad code that was here previously in the question?

Comment: This is perfect, thanks.  Sorry to be picky.  Now you have a nice clean question with a nice clean answer.  Anyone who ever has the same problem will no exactly how to fix it.

Comment: @azamsharp - it's ok to accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark. In that way it will not show up in the system as an *unanswered* question.